# How to compare two simple values?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript from an online course and I tried this:

```
var varNumber = 10;

if(varNumber==10) {
    alert("Number is 10");
}
```

I checked many times and I don't see any errors, but for some reason it just doesn't show up.

I also tried `document.write` instead of `alert` just in case my browser's blocking the pop-up, but it's still not showing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If that's not working, the code isn't running, you have issues elsewhere.

Comment: Works fine here: [**http://jsfiddle.net/BH7Af/**](http://jsfiddle.net/BH7Af/) and as a side note you are not doing a string comparison. `10` is seen as a number though `"10" == 10` will also be `true` as only using `==` does a data type conversion as well, unlike `===` where `"10" === 10` would not be the `true` but that's not what you are doing.

Comment: What you're showing here isn't string comparison, it's numeric comparison.  Make sure to use the Javascript Console which shows javascript errors; Chrome and Firefox make this easy.

Comment: Are you running this from within HTML? If so, can you post your HTML?

Comment: Then just try only `alert("Number is 10");` if alert doesn't show up ,the problem is not in your code.

Comment: Copy that snippet, open your browser console, paste it then press "Enter". It'll work

Comment: Check browser javascript enabled!

Comment: Thanks you guys for the support. I tried it again today and for some reason it works just fine. Yesterday I tried it in jsbin.com and notepad++, I also tried putting it in the html file and in the js file (though not at the same time) and nothing worked. Could be the browser!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly right. I tried it in Safari and Firefox.
Maybe you've disabled JavaScript in the Browser Settings. So check your settings.

Have you put it  tags in your html?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         [Your script]
      </script>
   <head>
   <body>
      <p>test</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I know you need 50 rep to post comments, but try posting some real answers, you'll get there pretty fast.

Comment: @adeneo: Nice and encouraging advice.

Comment: @Niklas - It's at least closer, I'll upvote it so you'll get a little closer to be able to comment (and that's half the fun).

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on here. It's not specified what's going on before or after your JS code. Just a guess, but have you tried calling the function onload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var varNumber = 10;

    if(varNumber==10) {
        alert("Number is 10");
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var varNumber = 10;

    if(parseInt(varNumber)==10) {
        alert("Number is 10");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information, along with your answer?